# create zip based on contents of a file list

Tags: terminal, compression

I created a file with diff files `diff-files.txt` it has 6000+ file paths in it. Now I want want to create a zip based on those files.

I know I can zip multiple files with:

```
zip diffedfiles.zip file1 folder1 -r
```

But that won't work with 6000+ files. Is there a way to zip it based on the content of `diff-files.txt`?

```
zip diffedfiles.zip {diff-files.txt} -r
```

Something like this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

On Linux you can use the -@ option:

> -@ file lists.   If a file list is specified as -@ [Not on MacOS],
>   zip takes the list of input files from standard input instead
>   of from the command line.  For example,
>
> ```
>           zip -@ foo
> ```
>
> will store the files listed one per line on stdin in foo.zip.

So in your case you should be able to do:

```
cat diff-files.txt | zip -@ diffedfiles.zip
```

Comment: Ancient post but this exact method works like a charm in windows (even in 2020)  with the Info-Zip console tool: ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/win32/zip300xn-x64.zip

Answer (score 3):

Got it:

```
zip diffedfiles.zip $(cat diff-files.txt) -r
```

Comment: This will hit bash's max args thing if you have a really long list of files.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods that work on all platforms:

1.

```
zip output.zip -r . -i@filelist.txt
```

2.

```
zip -@ - < filelist.txt > output.zip
```

These methods are not affected by command-line length limits.